# React action not triggering reducer

Tags: react-redux

I defined setUser action in chatActions.js file below. From the console log, I can see the setUser action is fired. But corresponding reducer is never triggered.

```
export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";
export const CLEAR_USER = "CLEAR_USER";

export const setUser = user => {
  console.log("In setUser");  <=== setUser action is fired for sure
  return {
    type: SET_USER,
    payload: {
      currentUser: user
    }
  };
};

export const clearUser = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_USER
  };
};
```

The reducer page is like below. From the console, I can see currentUser and isLoading being set to its initial state. But the state is never updated nevertheless the setUser action is fired.

```
import { createReducer } from '../../../app/common/util/reducerUtil'
import { SET_USER, CLEAR_USER, setUser, clearUser } from "../actions/chatActions"

const initialUserState = {
  currentUser: null,
  isLoading: "true"
};

export const chatUserReducer = (state = initialUserState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER:
      return {
        currentUser: action.payload.currentUser,
        isLoading: false
      };
    case CLEAR_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default createReducer(initialUserState, {
  [SET_USER]: setUser,
  [CLEAR_USER]: clearUser
})
```

Here is the rootReducer page:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as FormReducer } from 'redux-form';
import chatUserReducer from '../../features/chat/reducers/chatUserReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
    user: chatUserReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

The action is fired in the ChatDashboard component. user isn't null, and from above we can see setUser action is triggered, but somehow reducer isn't.

```
import { setUser, clearUser } from "../../chat/actions/chatActions";

const actions = {
  setUser,
  clearUser
}

const mapState = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser
})

class ChatComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) { <=== user is not null, this if condition is fulfilled
        this.props.setUser(user);
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapState, actions)(ChatComponent));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `chatUserReducer` like:

```
import {chatUserReducer} from '../../features/chat/reducers/chatUserReducer';
```

**RootReducer** will be like this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as FormReducer } from 'redux-form';
import {chatUserReducer} from '../../features/chat/reducers/chatUserReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
    user: chatUserReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Wow. The { } really solved my problem. Now I can see state being saved through reducer. Thanks a lot!!!